# Spark Web UI, shows non-zero Memory Storage numbers even if I don't persist data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

My spark application shows non-zero amounts in the Memory Storage even if I don't use persist or cache. Does spark cache my data even if I don't use persist/cache ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that Spark optimization is attempting to "broadcast" your smaller datasets to each worker to save on network usage.

Quoted from [Scaladocs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/broadcast/Broadcast.html)

> A broadcast variable. Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep
>   a read-only variable cached on each machine rather than shipping a
>   copy of it with tasks. They can be used, for example, to give every
>   node a copy of a large input dataset in an efficient manner. Spark
>   also attempts to distribute broadcast variables using efficient broadcast algorithms to reduce communication cost.

Also, in memory shuffling will cost you RAM.

Quoted from [Medium](https://medium.com/@foundev/you-won-t-believe-how-spark-shuffling-will-probably-bite-you-also-windowing-e39d07bf754e)

> Internally, results from individual map tasks are kept in memory until
>   they can’t fit. Then, these are sorted based on the target partition
>   and written to a single file. On the reduce side, tasks read the
>   relevant sorted blocks.

Comment: Indeed but none of the options mentioned by you should be visible in the web ui. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @humbletrader I do not see why they wouldn't be. These are just raw statistics about your clusters. They do not filter out shuffles nor broadcasts. I would be more concerned if they're all idling at 0.